# jZebra load error after Java update

Tags: java, applet

I have one web panel using jZebra applet to print to a ticket printer. All works ok under Java 1.6.29, but after updating to 1.7.10 applet load fails with jZebra.PrintApplet.class ClassNotFoundException. Html which loads the applet looks as:

```
...
<p>
<applet name="jZebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="./jzebra.jar" width="100" height="100"></applet>
</p>
...
```

jzebra.jar stays into the same folder as html file.

Do you know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend updating to qz-print 1.8.0 and using JNLP (or the newly provided applet tags) to deploy the applet.  If you choose to keep the applet tags, I would recommend updating them as they've changed considerably over the years:

```
<applet id="qz" archive="./qz-print.jar" name="QZ Print Plugin" code="qz.PrintApplet.class" width="55" height="55">
    <param name="jnlp_href" value="qz-print_jnlp.jnlp">
    <param name="cache_option" value="plugin">
    <param name="disable_logging" value="false">
    <param name="initial_focus" value="false">
</applet>
```

or if you require to keep the old 'jzebra' name

```
<applet name="jzebra" archive="./qz-print.jar" code="qz.PrintApplet.class" width="55" height="55">
    <param name="jnlp_href" value="qz-print_jnlp.jnlp">
    <param name="cache_option" value="plugin">
    <param name="disable_logging" value="false">
    <param name="initial_focus" value="false">
    <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>
```

In addition, I would recommend completely removing all versions of Java and re installing Java 7 as it has had multiple issues with the upgrade process.

From my experience, About 1 in 10 upgrades to Java 7 break.  There are a few solutions, but what's worked the best for me is uninstalling all previous versions, rebooting and reinstating Java 7.  Please understand this is not the normal "have you tried uninstalling first" patronage, this is a problem with the installer/upgrade process and we have many clients that spend hours trying to get our applet to load only to find the Oracle test page won't even work.

In addition, there were many changes in Java 7.  Particularly how it handles JNLP.  Some older version of Java 6 didn't have proper JNLP support so the .class parameter was needed as part of the applet tag.

To add even more frustration, for free applets like jzebra, Oracle blocks self-signed applets from running in more recent Java versions.  This was introduced with warnings in early Java 7 versions and they were completely blocked with 7u51.

But there is more... With 7u21, Oracle decided to block JavaScript (LiveConnect) if your Java Version is detected as being out of date and your security settings are set to high.  (High is the default BTW).  If you are curious as to what "out of date" is, this can be determined by a timer (3 months since that Java version was released) or a check to the Oracle site (i.e. a new version has become available).  Luckily Java 7 u51 added a whitelist feature to prevent this LiveConnect block behavior for specified URLs: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upcoming_exception_site_list_in but it must be added for each URL you access with a self-signed applet and/or outdated Java Version.

> **Note:**  You may also need to install the self-signed certificate into the "Signer CA" section of your Java security tab, but that is a security risk you should understand first and is likely out of the scope of this issue.

The new version of the jzebra applet (now called "qz-print") has some checks for some of these load issues as well as an alert dialog to resolve them.  They can be seen in sample.html.

Please download the latest print plugin and Java version and head over to http://qzindustries.com/support and we'll be sure to help you get this working.

-Tres

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the path to the the jzebra.jar relative to the root of the website like /dist/jzebra.jar.

It worked for me...